# unable to make a simple curved and rounded part, what am I missing?

Tags: bevel

I try to replicate the part in photo below in 3D with a slightly straighter shape as the versions available online looks too different of the original one but I'm facing difficulties.
(this is the part of a phone holder, the modified part allow more opening for bigger phones)

I designed the piece below but I'm unable to use the bevel feature to make round edges and get only the little angled part curved instead of "broken".

I tried a lot of different tutorials for 3 hours with bevel and modifiers with groups but it always gives weird results in the corners.

I've been using Blender many years ago to design some 3D parts but didn't use it for ages, I'm wondering if the base I draw is the right one for the shape I'm trying to achieve or if I'm not simply trying to go too straightforward even if the part seems to be something pretty simple.

Do you have any advice how I could achieve this?

Thanks

[image: part to replicate]
[image: 3D draft]

Edit: as requested I added new images
[image: side view]
[image: front view]
[image: top view]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what object you're trying to do, do you have another picture of the object?

Comment: Please, provide a better image of the part you want to model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create its profile:

[image]

Extrude to give it thickness, bevel to round the corner:

[image]

Bevel the edges to round, enable the *Clamp Overlap* option, then merge by distance to remove the overlapping vertices, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!